# windows or powershell command to merge multiple csvfiles to singlefile side by side (column wise)

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried with below commands, it copied one below the other lines, but i want to copy or paste side by side. like in unix we have paste command.

example

File1.csv:

```
company factory Industry
```

File1.csv:

```
fruites vegies
Flowers Colours
```

i want the date in file3 as below

- column1: company factory Industry fruites vegies
- column2: will be empty 1st 3cells  Flowers Colours

tried as below, but no luck

```
Copy\b *.csv file3.csv
```

and

```
type file1.csv > file3.csv
type file2.csv >> file3.csv
```

Comment: I do not think you have listed enough info for someone to help you. I have done stuff like this, maybe I can help a little. 1st, what were you using in Unix to copy and paste side by side programmatically? If you give the name, maybe we could recommend an equivalent tool. Second, you are trying to merge headers, you need to variablize the headers, but you didn't state if this is a 1 time thing, or if you need to predict the header values (one time thing is easier). Last, here are some commands that might help you, "Get-Content" and "Write-Content".

Comment: This can be done with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1), a [`for loop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1), `-join` operator and [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.1).